# Files.move on a unwritable file throws AccessDeniedException on Windows but not Linux

Tags: java

I am currently using `Files.move(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING)`. My unit test passes on Windows but fails on Linux:

```java
void test() throws IOException {
  FIle unwritableFile = new File(TEST_DIR, UNWRITABLE_FILE);
  unwritableFile.createNewFile();
  unwritableFile.setReadOnly();
  // execute method that calls Files.move
```

Why is AccessDeniedException not being thrown on Linux? How do I create an unwritable file for both OS such that it throws on both OSes?

Comment: This is consistent with ext4:  I can use a `mv` command in Linux on a file which has no write permissions (or has no permissions at all, in fact).  Putting the file in a directory which you cannot read or list may accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Solution

This example demonstrates how to make a file read-only by using file.setReadOnly() and file.canWrite() methods of File class.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      File file = new File("C:/java.txt");
      System.out.println(file.setReadOnly());
      System.out.println(file.canWrite());
   }
}
```

Result

The above code sample will produce the following result.To test the example,first create a file 'java.txt' in 'C' drive.

true

false